# Trigger calls Stored Procedure and if we we do a select will the return values be the new or old?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers

Using MS SQL Server, a Trigger calls a Stored Procedure which internally makes a select, will the return values be the new or old ones?

I know that inside the trigger I can access them by `FROM INSERTED i inner join DELETED`, but in this case I want to reuse (cannot change it) an existing Stored Procedure that internally makes a select on the triggered table and processes some logic with them. I just want to know if I can be sure that the existing logic will work or not (by accessing the NEW values).

I can simply try to simulate it with one update... But maybe there are other cases (example: using transactions or something else) that I maybe not be aware and never test it that could result in a different case.

I decided to ask someone else that might know better. Thank you.

Comment: Calling a Procedure from within a trigger is generally a bad idea. A trigger should have as minimal impact as possible on the calling DML statement. Ideally put the data that needs to be consumed by the procedure into a table, and then have a regularly scheduled task execute that procedure (which consumes and uses that data in a set based manner).

Comment: @Larnu I understand and I would agree with you... however in this specific case the existing SP is already complicated and I do not want to have its internal logic duplicated and prone to someone forgeting to change it twice if I would follow your recomendation.

Comment: That doesn't make it "right" to put the call into a procedure. In fact if the procedure is complicated (and slow?) then it's all the *more* reason  to not put the call in the trigger; it'll be awful for your performance.

Comment: No matter if you or I agree or not, my question is still valid. Will the SP obtain the new or old data?

Comment: The Procedure can't access the `inserted` and `deleted` objects if that's what you're asking, no. If you're asking will it "see" the data effected by the DML statement, then yes, because it's inside the same transaction scope. You can easily test this in a Sandbox Environment. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0c52dfe17775a7229ae6510464d469cb)

Answer (score 0):

AFTER triggers (the default) fire after the DML action. When the proc is called within the trigger, the tables will reflect changes made by the statement that fired the trigger as well changes made within the trigger before calling the proc.

Note changes are uncommitted until the trigger completes or explict transaction later committed.

Answer (score 0):

Since the procedure is running in the same transaction as the (presumably, "after") trigger, it will see the uncommitted data.

I hope you see the implications of that: the trigger is executing as part of the transaction started by the DML statement that caused it to fire, so the stored procedure is part of the same transaction, so a "complicated" stored procedure means that transaction stays open longer, holding locks longer, making responses back to users slower, etc etc.

Also, you said

> internally makes a select on the triggered table and processes some logic with them.

if you just mean that the procedure is selecting the data in order to do some complex processing and then write it to somewhere else inside the database, ok, that's not great (for reasons given above), but it will "work".

But just in case you mean you are doing some work on the data in the procedure and then returning that back to the client application, [Don't do that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#general-trigger-considerations)

> The ability to return results from triggers will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Triggers that return result sets may cause unexpected behavior in applications that aren't designed to work with them. Avoid returning result sets from triggers in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently do. To prevent triggers from returning result sets, set the disallow results from triggers option to 1.